# how to used wordpress function inside the custom function?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
<?php function tms_footerWidget(){
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `tms_footerColumns` FROM `wp_tms`");
        foreach ($results as $row) {
           $tms_footerWidget = $row->tms_footerColumns;
            }
      $colsOne="<div class=\"col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12\"><div class=\"thumbnail\"><?php dynamic_sidebar('tms_footer2'); ?></div>";
    return $colsOne;
  }
?>
```

and after i have used this function in my html code and i run my php page at that that time these function could not working ..so i see in inspect elements following type of the error plz..tell me answer of this problem...

Comment: Where is the error? Provide one....

Comment: <!--?php echo dynamic_sidebar('tms_footer1'); ?-->  this error provide.when i was compiling php page..

Comment: Post the error... how should one help you, if you dont paste your error....

Answer (score 0):

You haveto pass wordpress hook as you are using custom function.
(i.e., add_action('wp_head', 'tms_footerWidget'))

Comment: how i add this function in my footer page?

Comment: add this line:

$colsOne="<div class=\"col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12\"><div class=\"thumbnail\">".dynamic_sidebar('tms_footer2')." ?></div>";

instead of:

 $colsOne="<div class=\"col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12\"><div class=\"thumbnail\"><?php dynamic_sidebar('tms_footer2'); ?></div>";