# How to call WordPress widget without using dynamic_widget function

Tags: widget, wordpress

For calling widgets in WordPress, I know that I can use `dynamic_widget` function, but I want to call a widget differently.

Is there any other method to call a WordPress widget without using the WordPress function?

Comment: Do you want to call a widget from outside WordPress or what should that "other method" do?

Comment: I want call widget in WordPress.but I want need to call a widget different way

Comment: "a different way" - what do you mean? What exactly do you want to achieve / what does not work? Have you tried `the_widget` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget)?

Comment: Don't use Wordpress at all if you are not going to use its functions. You want to pully a car that has **no** problem with an old scrap donkey car with a dead donkey. This how much sense your question makes

Comment: you have been see my problem in answer part?

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass wordpress hook as you are using custom function.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'tms_footerWidget')
```

Comment: This is not a answer.

Comment: I Know that but this question is on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509625/how-to-used-wordpress-function-inside-the-custom-function

Comment: File an edit to your original question, do **not** post edits or questions as answers. Why are you still doing it if you know. You can get your account suspended for this

Comment: who are you? and its my account . so don't tell me what should i do? just do your own work? don't tell me again?

Comment: Listen here, mind your manners. There are policies which you **will** abide by. I handled a low quality flag on this question as it was flagged as low quality due to it not being an answer.

Comment: sorry for that ..but i don't mine you had given me low quality flag.because I was already solve my problem my self ...